# Create Access table from text file

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado

I need to create an access (2007) table from a text file. I know ahead of time what columns should exist, but from time to time the vendors slip up and submit a text file that contains an incorrect number of columns. So I don't want to specify the columns in advance. I want to load all data as text into whatever columns exist. Then I will do QC.

The columns are pipe delimited and there are over 200 columns per record. There are no column headers, but there is one line of header text for the file, and one line at the end that states how many records there are. There may be anywhere from 1 to over 5,000 records in a text file. Records are identified with CRLF (windows).

Here is what I have so far, and it works (in that it reads the file and places the correct information in the recordset (columns and records), and I can count the number of records), except that the SELECT INTO gives me an error:

```
Sub OpenTextADO(strFileName As String, strPath As String)

  Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim fld As ADODB.Field
  Dim recs As Integer
  Dim strRecord As String
  Dim strSQL As String

  recs = 0

  Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

  If Right(strFileName, 3) = "txt" Then
    'cn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" & "DBQ=" & strPath & "\"  'need schema.ini file
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strPath & "\;Extended Properties='text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited(|)'"  'need schema.ini file
  End If

  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  rs.Open "SELECT * INTO TESTTEXT FROM [" & strFileName & "]", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText


  'Do Until rs.EOF
  '  For Each fld In rs.Fields
  '    strRecord = strRecord & "|" & fld.Value
  '  Next fld
  '  strRecord = strRecord & vbCr
  '  recs = recs + 1
  '  rs.MoveNext
  'Loop

  'Debug.Print strRecord

  'recs = rs.RecordCount

  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  MsgBox "Text was opened and there are " & recs & " records in the table."

  cn.Close
  Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

NOTE: I included both the OLEDB version and the text driver version - they both seem to operate identically. I also created a schema.ini file that looks like this:

```
[test.txt]
Format=Delimited(|)
ColNameHeader=False
```

Both drivers seem to need this to desregard column headers, despite the "HDR=No" in the OLEDB version.

The error I get is:  "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only".

I appreciate any help.

Comment: How many of these are you doing?  What about using the import wizard?

Comment: I use the import wizard now, but that's getting impractical. I started getting maybe 5 or 6 of these files a week, now I'm getting 20-30 a week, and will probably get more.

Answer (score 3):

Could you do a sequential read of the text file, using the count of pipe-delimited fields in the first data line of the file to create a table with the proper number of columns, then just write subsequent lines into that table?  I just threw the following together, but it seems to work.

```
Public Function import_txt_to_db(strFile As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo ErrHandle

Dim strLine As String
Dim intFileNum As Integer

Dim blnFirstLine As Boolean
blnFirstLine = True

Dim varArray As Variant

intFileNum = FreeFile

Open strFile For Input Access Read As intFileNum

Do While Not EOF(intFileNum)

    Line Input #intFileNum, strLine
    varArray = Split(strLine, "|")

    If blnFirstLine = True Then
        'Use count of fields in first line to determine # of columns to create
        Dim intColCount As Integer
        intColCount = UBound(varArray)

        Dim strQry As String
        strQry = "CREATE TABLE tblImport ("
        Dim intCtr As Integer
        For intCtr = 1 To intColCount + 1
            strQry = strQry & "[COLUMN_" & intCtr & "] TEXT(255),"
        Next intCtr

        strQry = Left(strQry, Len(strQry) - 1) & ")" 'get rid of terminal comma

        CurrentDb.Execute strQry

        blnFirstLine = False

    End If

    Dim strQry2 As String
    strQry2 = "INSERT INTO tblImport VALUES('" & Replace(strLine, "|", "','") & "')"

    CurrentDb.Execute strQry2

Loop

Close #intFileNum
import_txt_to_db = True

Exit Function

ErrHandle:
import_txt_to_db = False

End Function
```

I did a simple test with the folowing five-line text file

```
Thomas|Jefferson|Virginia
Bill|Clinton|Arkansas
Jimmy|Carter|Georgia
Lyndon|Johnson|Texas
George|Washington|Virginia
```

After running the code, here's my (simple) table:

[image: vba-generated table]